# Анимация в MixItUp работает не корректно

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Здравствуйте. 
Работаю через gulp, если это имеет какое-то значение. При клике на кнопки, выборка идет, но анимации нет. Просто все img исчезают, контент снизу поднимается под кнопки, потом опять вниз и появляются выбранные img. В чем моя ошибка? Заранее спасибо

```js
$(function(){

    var mixer = mixitup('.port_items');

};
```

```css
.port_box {
  text-align: center;
}

.port_box button {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.port_box .mixitup-control-active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #998675;
}

.port_items .col-md-4 {
  padding: 15px;
}

.port_items .col-md-4 img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="port_box">
    <button data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button data-filter=".category-a">Web Design</button>
    <button data-filter=".category-b">Mobile App</button>
    <button data-filter=".category-c">Illustration</button>
    <button data-filter=".category-d">Photography</button>
  </div>
  <div class="port_items">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mix category-b"><img src="http://lookw.ru/1/240/1380318322-leopardi-ch3--32.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="box_bottom">
        <p>Claritas Etiam Processus</p>
        <div class="text_1">Photography, Nature</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mix category-d"><img src="http://333v.ru/uploads/28/28b4bb977bda60daad7922bfe3f637cf.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="box_bottom">
        <p>Quam Nutamus Farum</p>
        <div class="text_1">Graphic Design, Mock-Up</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mix category-c"><img src="http://www.wallcoo.com/nature/Beauty_of_nature_1920x1200/wallpapers/1280x800/HD_beautiful_nature_landsacpe_200701052008-2054.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="box_bottom">
        <p>Usus Legentis Videntur</p>
        <div class="text_1">Photography, Holiday</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mix category-d"><img src="https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/3/7/436445025072999/sport-kvadrocikl-quadrocycle-atv-quad-bike-gonshhik-racer-snaryazhenie-shlem-koncentraciya-cel-skorost-kantri-kross-gonka-gryaz-dozhd-bezdorozhe-pryzhok-preodolenie-prepyatstviya-wallpaper.jpg"
        alt="">
      <div class="box_bottom">
        <p>Claritas Etiam Processus</p>
        <div class="text_1">Photography, Nature</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mix category-a"><img src="http://hdwallpapers8k.com/wp-content/uploads/palm-tress-at-ocean-shore.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="box_bottom">
        <p>Quam Nutamus Farum</p>
        <div class="text_1">Graphic Design, Mock-Up</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mix category-d"><img src="http://hdwallpaper-images.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Beautiful-Waterfall-Wallpapers-HD-images-1000x667.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="box_bottom">
        <p>Usus Legentis Videntur</p>
        <div class="text_1">Photography, Holiday</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ты видать js не  весь добавил, проверь свой пример

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуте =)
 Элементам контейнера **port_items** нужно добавить некоторые стили
То есть где у вас определены классы category-#, Добавте еще один общий класс, к примеру **items** со следующими стилями:

```
  .items {
      width: 23%;
      margin: 1%;
      display: none;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: Не помогло. После третьего клика по кнопкам вообще начинает глючить) я думаю проблема связана с gulp, потому что я пробовал запустить этот кусок кода по простому - html+css+js - анимация работала как положено